# Ajax form is not returning PHP data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a login system hat uses ajax and php. The form checks are done using javascript then the form data sent to php to checked against the data base.
The php will return 1 if the user is not in the database.
I have done this before and it has worked fine but here, 'NOTHING'.

JQuery version:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

AJAX:

```
var pass = $('#pass').val();
var user = $('#user').val();
$.ajax({
url: 'func/check-login.php',
type: 'POST',
data:{user:user,pass:pass},
complete: function(e){
    alert(parseInt(e));
        if(e === 1){
            $('#main_error').html('That username password combination is incorrect');
        }else{
            alert('Log user in');
        }
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include '../DB.func/connect.php';
if(!empty($_POST)){

        $_POST['user'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $_POST['pass'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        if($username == ''){$user_err = 'You must insert tour username';}
        if($password == ''){$pass_err = 'You must insert your passowrd';}
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_admin WHERE user_name = '$username' OR email = '$username' AND password = '".md5($password)."'")or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows != 0){
        //login
        echo '0';
    }else{
        echo 1;
    }
}else{
    echo '1';
}

?>
```

The alert in the complete function of the Ajax isn't opening with anything.

Answer (score 1):

try to use event success instead of complete:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'func/check-login.php',
type: 'POST',
data:{user:user,pass:pass},
success: function(e){
    alert(parseInt(e));
        if(e === 1){
            $('#main_error').html('That username password combination is incorrect');
        }else{
            alert('Log user in');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thats it success works, whats the difference between success and complete and they the same sort of thing

Comment: Success : This event is only called if the request was successful (no errors from the server, no errors with the data).
Complete: This event is called regardless of if the request was successful, or not. You will always receive a complete callback, even for synchronous requests. @PaulLedger

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do `e = parseInt(e)`. You're currently just alerting `parseInt(e)`. `'1' === 1` is false. `echo 1` and `echo '1'` both come back as a string from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Call your ajax function with success, and error methods,

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'func/check-login.php',
   type: 'POST', 
   data:{user:user,pass:pass},
   success: function(e){

        if( parseInt(e) === 1){
            $('#main_error').html('That username password combination is incorrect');
        }else{
            alert('Log user in');
        }
    },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //for checking error console these variables
             console.log( jqXHR);
             console.log( textStatus);
             console.log( errorThrown);
        }
    });
```